# Prove that $(X'X)^{-1}X'AX(X'X)^{-1}-(X'A^{-1}X)^{-1}$ is positive definite

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

How to prove if A is a positive definite matrix, then $(X'X)^{-1}X'AX(X'X)^{-1}-(X'A^{-1}X)^{-1}$ is also positive definite? Here $X'$ denotes the transpose of $X$. $A$ is square and $X$ is $n\times m$.

Comment: Perhaps you should post what you have tried?

Comment: What is $X$? What is $X'$? Is $X$ an invertible matrix and $X'=X^*$?

Comment: Sorry, X' is transpose of X.

Comment: I don't have a clue on how to prove...

Comment: And $X$ is a square matrix? Then this is surely false as your expression simplifies to $0$.

Comment: It seems to me that on simplifying the first term, it exactly equals the second, making the difference the zero matrix for all (invertible and square) $A$ and $X$?

Comment: I add necessary restriction for X, as attached.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Presumably $X$ is a full-rank tall matrix ($n\ge m$). Let $X=U\pmatrix{\Sigma\\ 0}V'$ be a singular value decomposition of $X$, where $\Sigma$ is a positive diagonal matrix. Then the statement $(X'X)^{-1}X'AX(X'X)^{-1}-(X'A^{-1}X)^{-1}\color{red}{\succeq}0$ (note: it's positive semidefinite, but *not* necessarily positive definite; for instance, it is zero when $A=I$) can be transformed into the form of
$$
\pmatrix{I&0}M^{-1}\pmatrix{I\\ 0}\succeq\left(\pmatrix{I&0}M\pmatrix{I\\ 0}\right)^{-1},\tag{1}
$$
where
$$
M=\pmatrix{\Sigma\\ &I}UA^{-1}U'\pmatrix{\Sigma\\ &I}
$$
is positive definite. Write $M=\pmatrix{X&Y'\\ Y&Z}$, where $X$ has the size as $\Sigma$. As $M$ is positive definite, so are $Z$, its [Schur complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement) $X-Y'Z^{-1}Y$, and also $(X-Y'Z^{-1}Y)^{-1}$. Therefore statement $(1)$ is equivalent to $(X-Y'Z^{-1}Y)^{-1} \succeq X^{-1}$, which, by [strict partial ordering of positive definte matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix#Further_properties), is equivalent to $X-Y'Z^{-1}Y \preceq X$. Now this is obvious.

Comment: Could I ask where do you use X=USV′?

Comment: @mathlearner The SVD $X=USV'$ is used to transform the statement $(X'X)^{-1}X'AX(X'X)^{-1}\succeq(X'A^{-1}X)^{-1}$ into the form of $\pmatrix{I&0}M^{-1}\pmatrix{I\\ 0}\succeq\left(\pmatrix{I&0}M\pmatrix{I\\ 0}\right)^{-1}$.

Comment: @ user1551  Thank you very much! Although I still don't quite understand the SVD and Schur complement, I think you have provided enough information to learn them.