# Prove that $A^{-1} - X(X'AX)^{-1}X'$ is positive semidefinite

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-semidefinite

Assume that $X$ is a full rank $n \times k$ matrix and that $A$ is $n\times n$ non-singular matrix positive semidefinite. I would like to show that $A^{-1} - X(X'AX)^{-1}X'$ is positive semidefinite.

I tried to use the singular decomposition of $X$ as suggested in this [similar post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/379002/prove-that-xx-1xaxxx-1-xa-1x-1-is-positive-definite). But I can't get the result.

Comment: I guess that you're assuming $A$ is self-adjoint? Otherwise the matrix $A^{-1} - X(X'AX)^{-1} X'$ need not be self-adjoint.

Comment: Even then there are counterexamples. You'll need $A$ to be positive semidefinite itself to have any hope of this result being true (see [Schur Complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement#Conditions_for_positive_definiteness_and_semi-definiteness)).

Comment: Thanks. Yes I forgot to mention that A is positive definite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that $X'$ means $X^\ast$. Your statement is false in general. Since $f(A)=A^{-1}-X(X'AX)^{-1}X'$ is not identically zero, if $f(A)$ is nonzero and positive semidefinite, then $f(-A)$ is nonzero and negative semidefinite.

The statement is true when $A$ is positive definite, however. Let $A=LL'$ (e.g. take $L$ as $A^{1/2}$ or the Cholesky factor of $A$) and let $Y=L'X$. Then
$$
A^{-1}-X(X'AX)^{-1}X'=(L^{-1})'\big(I-Y(Y'Y)^{-1}Y'\big)L^{-1}.
$$
Since $L$ is nonsingular and $I-Y(Y'Y)^{-1}Y'$ is an orthogonal projection, the LHS of the above is positive semidefinite.